# How can we access the files in the Data Folder when we publish the Vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I have added some files that I need to be downloaded to the Application start up path. So I set Build Action as content now the files have been copied some where

C:\Documents and Settings\TestUser.ANNAM\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\Data\HVDRBMY5.8AA\858AT9VM.TNP\test..tion_2d7cfc137d9c2c74_0001.0013_432bd4561850d290\Data

How can access file from the application. My problem since it is a dynamic path will it be same folder count so that we can use like ....\Data\ Some think like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath` this will return the directory where the application is stored.